# How to access the no data value of a raster with GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, nodata

Is there a similar way as in ArcPy

```
import arcpy

desc=arcpy.Describe('rasterName')
print desc.noDataValue
```

to access the no data value using GDAL?

Comment: yes, although by the question's title I did not find this post as an answer to my question.

Comment: Now the questions are linked, so if anyone searches for the keywords in either title, they will find both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is given in [Python:Alternatives to using Arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/35115/2581)

```
from osgeo import gdal
srs = gdal.Open("dem_maido_tipe.tif")
srs.RasterCount
1
print(srs.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue())
-32768.0

srs = gdal.Open("geol_map.tif")
srs.RasterCount
3
print(srs.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue())
None
for i in range(srs.RasterCount):
     print(srs.GetRasterBand(i+1).GetNoDataValue())
None
None
None
```

And you can also use [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), more user-friendly library of GDAL data model

```
import rasterio
src = rasterio.open("dem_maido_tipe.tif")
print(src.nodatavals)
(-32768.0,)
src = rasterio.open("geol_map.tif")
print(src.nodatavals)
(None, None, None)
```